# How to make the setValue function work in PHPWord?

Tags: php, phpword, setvalue

I have retrieved the text of a document with PHPWord. Now I would like to modify the data with the setValue function. When I try to do it, it gives me this error:

```
[05-Jan-2023 17:44:37 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught BadMethodCallException: Method setvalue is not defined. in /home/bloggors/translatedocs.bloggors.com/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/PhpWord.php:148
Stack trace:
#0 /home/bloggors/translatedocs.bloggors.com/controller/test.php(11): PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord->__call('setvalue', Array)
```

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\AbstractContainer;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Text;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory as WordIOFactory;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$source = 'test/sample-doc-file-for-testing-1.doc';
$objReader = WordIOFactory::createReader('MsDoc');
$phpWord = $objReader->load($source); // instance of \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord
$phpWord->setValue('Lorem', 'John');

?>
```

**What should I do to solve this problem please?**

Comment: According to the docs (https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates-processing.html#setvalue), the setValue is a method of a template processor. So, you'd need to do something as `$tp = new TemplateProcessor('your-template.docx');` and then use `$tp->setValue(etc)`.

Comment: I inserted this piece of code as you showed me. But it doesn't work and it sent me the same error as before.
**Here is the code:**
`$tp = new TemplateProcessor($source); 
$tp->setValue('Lorem', 'John');`

Comment: @césar-rodriguez Do I have to add another use or namespace value in the header for it to work or what?

Comment: I tried to add this in the header.
`use PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor;`
 It sent me this error now.
`[05-Jan-2023 19:09:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::getFromName(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in 
/home/bloggors/translatedocs.bloggors.com/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Shared/ZipArchive.php on line 212`

Comment: According to the docs, the template processor `$source` must be an OOXML document. So, you'd need to pass the whole .docx filepath, not only the text (as it seems to be the case in your code). P.S.: the docx file is a .zip in disguise, hence the error makes sense.

Comment: Maybe our approach is unnefective. What's your need? `setValue` is for substituting variable names in docx files. If you have the file text in a string, the normal string replacing functions would make it.

Comment: No. The variable $source contains an OXML file and it is the path to the docx file that is stored in the variable.

**Here is the complete code:**
`<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\AbstractContainer;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Text;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory as WordIOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor;

$source = 'test/sample-doc-file-for-testing-1.doc';
$templateProcessor = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createReader('MsDoc')->TemplateProcessor($source);
$templateProcessor->setValue('firstname', 'John');
`

Comment: @césar-rodriguez I want to translate the content of .doc and .docx, .ppt, pptx files and also all types of files that PHPWORD gives the possibility to work with and replace it with another translation content.

Answer (score 0):

setValue is a method for TemplateProcessor. You need to use an exisiting .docx file that has variables with the specified search pattern in them.

Let's say you have template.docx:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ${varName} adipiscing elit.
```

What setValue does is replace the ${varName} with the value you specify. For example:

```
$tProcessor = new TemplateProcessor('path/to/template.docx');
$tProcessor->setValue('varName', 'Replacement Text');
```

So template.docx becomes:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Replacement Text adipiscing elit.
```

You can replace the variables with text, charts, etc by using TemplateProcessor. When you're done replacing the variables you can save the edited file to a new file:

```
$tProcessor->saveAs('path/to/newFile.docx');
```

By using saveAs, the original template file won't be modified.

By default the search pattern is ${varName}, but you can specify a custom search pattern if you want. Please refer to the documentation: https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates-processing.html

Don't forget to include the TemplateProcessor if you're editor doesn't automatically add it:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor;
```